# How does one get shared libraries and header files to install Zita-at1

Tags: software-installation, libraries

I am trying to install a program called Zita-at1. In the installation guide it says:

> To install, cd to the source directory, make, sudo make install, make
>   clean.
>
> To build this version, you need the shared libraries
>
> ```
> libclthreads-2.4.0   libclxclient-3.9.0
> ```
>
> and the corresponding header files. They are available at
>
> http://kokkinizita.linuxaudio.org/linuxaudio/downloads
>
> To install into `/usr` instead of `/usr/local` modify the definition of
>   'PREFIX' in the Makefile.

I do not know what is meant by "make, make install or make clean". Neither how to "get" the share libraries I need. Are these installed by using a terminal command?

I have downloaded to header files, but do not know where to put them or what to do with them. I basically need help decoding these instructions

Comment: I would imagine that they need to be in the location the Makefile looks for them. What have you tried thus far? have you searched for the required libraries? https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=libclthreads-2.4.0&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 2):

Search to find which Ubuntu package mentions desired library

```
apt-file search libclthreads
```

it responds with

```
libclthreads-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclthreads.so
libclthreads-dev: /usr/share/doc/libclthreads-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
libclthreads-dev: /usr/share/doc/libclthreads-dev/copyright
libclthreads2: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclthreads.so.2
libclthreads2: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclthreads.so.2.4.0
libclthreads2: /usr/share/doc/libclthreads2/changelog.Debian.gz
libclthreads2: /usr/share/doc/libclthreads2/copyright
```

Packages ending with `-dev` indicate they contain header files so install using

```
sudo apt-get install libclthreads-dev
```

which responds with verbiage including

```
Preparing to unpack .../libclthreads2_2.4.0-5_amd64.deb ...
```

which confirms the matching release ... similar for the other library

```
apt-file search  libclxclient
```

you can see it mentions a `-dev` so pick that one

```
sudo apt-get install libclxclient-dev
```

Now after downloading and expanding the Zita-at1 go into its source code dir and compile it

```
cd zita-at1-0.4.0/source 
make
```

it fails with

```
stens@bodhisattva ~/other_src/zita-at1-0.4.0/source $ make
g++ -O2 -ffast-math -Wall -MMD -MP -march=native -MMD -MP -DVERSION=\"0.4.0\" -DSHARED=\"/usr/local/share/zita-at1\" -I/usr/X11R6/include `freetype-config --cflags`  -c -o zita-at1.o zita-at1.cc
In file included from jclient.h:28:0,
                 from zita-at1.cc:29:
retuner.h:27:38: fatal error: zita-resampler/resampler.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
<builtin>: recipe for target 'zita-at1.o' failed
make: *** [zita-at1.o] Error 1
```

so I just discovered that missing header lives in zita-resampler which is listed at same link you provide so lets first install that ... once downloaded and expanded then to compile

```
cd zita-resampler-1.6.0/libs 
make
```

which gives output

```
g++ -Wall -fPIC -O2 -ffast-math -march=native -I. -D_REENTRANT -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS  -c -o resampler.o resampler.cc
g++ -Wall -fPIC -O2 -ffast-math -march=native -I. -D_REENTRANT -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS  -c -o vresampler.o vresampler.cc
g++ -Wall -fPIC -O2 -ffast-math -march=native -I. -D_REENTRANT -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS  -c -o resampler-table.o resampler-table.cc
g++ -Wall -fPIC -O2 -ffast-math -march=native -I. -D_REENTRANT -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS  -c -o cresampler.o cresampler.cc
g++ -shared  -Wl,-soname,libzita-resampler.so.1 -o libzita-resampler.so.1.6.0 resampler.o vresampler.o resampler-table.o cresampler.o
```

now install it

```
cd zita-resampler-1.6.0/libs
sudo make install
```

so finally go back to our original failed `make` and retry now that its upstream library is installed

```
cd zita-at1-0.4.0/source 
make
```

which generates its executable file

```
zita-at1
```

Done ... if when you issue `make` it says not found then install your compile tools by issuing

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

which will give you make plus other compile tools